# Obtain separate columns in a matrix

Tags: matrix, multiple-columns, dolphindb, transformation-matrix

```
#0 #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 #8 #9  #10 #11
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --- --- ---
1  11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91  101 111
2  12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92  102 112
3  13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93  103 113
4  14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 94  104 114
5  15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95  105 115
6  16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86 96  106 116
7  17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87 97  107 117
8  18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88 98  108 118
9  19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99  109 119
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120
```

I can access consecutive columns at the position 1-4 using `m[:, 1:5]` in DolphinDB, but it cannot work when retrieving separate columns. For example, I’d like to obtain the columns at the position 1, 9, and 10, but `m[:,[1,9,10]]` returns an error message:

```
 colIndex must be a scalar value or a range
```

How can I access separate columns in a matrix in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the matrix with `m[1,9,10]` to retrieve the columns:

```
m=1..120$10:12;
index= 1 9 10
m[index]
```

output

```
#0 #1  #2 
-- --- ---
11 91  101
12 92  102
13 93  103
14 94  104
15 95  105
16 96  106
17 97  107
18 98  108
19 99  109
20 100 110
```

To obtain separate rows (e.g. rows 1, 3 and 5):

```
m[1 3 5,0..(cols(m)-1)]
```

output

```
#0 #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 #8 #9 #10 #11
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --- ---
2  12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92 102 112
4  14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 94 104 114
6  16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86 96 106 116
```

To obtain specific cells:

```
m[1 3 5,1 9 10]
```

---

```
#0 #1 #2 
-- -- ---
12 92 102
14 94 104
16 96 106
```

DolphinDB version 2.00.8 also offers a new function loc which has the same function as pandas `loc`. For example:

```
m.loc(colFilter=(1..12 in[1,9,10]), view=false)
```